# Why does adding a typed dataset in a WCF service force the client to use arrays for collections?

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio

I have a WCF service and a WCF client. The service uses methods which return generic lists and the client's service reference collection type is set to generic list. Everything works fine.

I added a method to the WCF service which returns a typed dataset. First operation contract to return a dataset. Updated the service reference in the client and it broke everything. All the lists were converted to arrays even though the collection type is set to generic list.

I thought something went bad so I deleted the service reference, reran VS, created the service reference from scratch and still all the collections have been converted to arrays instead of lists.

I confirmed that the dataset caused this because when I removed the new method from the WCF service and updated the reference, all the collections went back to lists.

I need to use the dataset as is. How can I use it and leave the rest of the lists intact? Why is the typed dataset interfering with the type of the rest of the collections being used? I am using VS 2013 update 2 with .NET 4.5.1.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure you can transfer datasets like that over wcf services but what you can do is return string that will be serialized dataset and deserialize it at the other end.

Comment: Sure I can. It's just a class. WCF already does the serialization and deserialization. But I might try to serialize it myself as string so WCF doesn't know it's a dataset.

Comment: @MatijaK. You can transfer datasets over the wire. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19561/Introducing-ADONET-and-the-Typed-DataSet.htm

Comment: DO NOT RETURN DATASETS FROM WEB SERVICES!!!! http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx

Comment: @Tom I said I need to use the dataset as is. It's a legacy app. I am aware of datasets  not being optimal and IT'S NOT WRONG technically. However this post is about something specific. It's not about whether I can or not use datasets as return types. and please stop using all caps. It's like shouting.

Comment: Sorry, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the service method to a legacy web service (asmx) service.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that when you add the service reference via visual studio, under the hood, Visual Studio calls svcutil.exe to generate your proxy. This is good, because as your screen shot shows, svcutil is able to interpret collections on the exposed service definition wsdl as `List<T>`.

This generally works well for simple contracts.

Now, for an obscure reason known only to Microsoft, svcutil has a rather [fussy interpretation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of XSD, which means that for service definitions which fall outside this interpretation, VS will fall back on using good old xsd.exe, which happens to NOT support collections as `List<T>`.

Generally you don't notice this because most service definitions are relatively simple and adhere to the rules. Dumping something like a .net DataSet object into the service contract however, and you're service definition becomes so heinously complex that VS is going to have to go with using xsd.exe to generate your code.

And therein lies the problem.

Some things you can try:

1. Extract out the XSD from the service WSDL and try calling svcutil directly: `svcutil /o:file.cs /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List schema.xsd` (probably won't work but I would try just in case)
2. Modify your generated code manually, replacing all arrays with Lists (ouch)
3. Don't dump a .net dataset into your service definition (this is my favorite)
4. Use a tool like [XsdArrayToList](http://www.stefanbader.ch/xsdcsarr2l-exe-refactor-xsd-array-to-list/) - this will allow you to re-gen your gen'd code.

Comment: What you said doesn't seem to be happening. I used Process Monitor and couldn't find xsd.exe nor svcutil.exe usage in the capture. Then I renamed all the instances of those execuatbles on the computer and VS was still able to create the service reference. Maybe VS 2013 is using an api. List<T> and typed datasets even non typed datasets are .NET artifacts so I expected the proxy file to have both. Either both to support a .NET client (in my case) or none to support non .NET clients. But supporting one and not the other in WCF doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have moved the service method to a legacy web service (asmx) service. Everything needs to be standard so other developers can work without breaking anything and not to spend troubleshooting issues.